# Display PlaceholderText When DateTime is null in CalendarPicker in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I have a `CalendarDatePicker` with some `DateTime` object bound to it's Date property. When the bound Date is `null`, The picker is showing the least date available (`1/1/1922`). How can I make the picker just show the `PlaceHolderText` when the bound Date is `null`? The `FuzzyDateConverter` is just a simple converter which converts individual day, month and year to `DateTime` Object...

The CalendarPicker is Below.

```xml
<CalendarDatePicker 
    PlaceholderText="Pick a date"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    DateFormat="{}{day.integer}/{month.integer}/{year.full}"
    LightDismissOverlayMode="On"
    Date="{x:Bind ViewModel.CompletedAt, Converter={StaticResource FuzzyDateConverter}}"/>
```

And the Converter is below...

```cs
public class FuzzyToDateTimeObject : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return new DateTimeOffset(((DateTime)value).ToUniversalTime());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return ((DateTimeOffset)value).DateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I set the binding `Date` to null, the program has an error, could you show your viewmodel?

Comment: You might already solved this but I posted an answer for the others.

Comment: Thanks @Junije Zhu - MSFT . I've soleved the problem with the help of Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it shows the "Pick a date" placeholder when `CompletedAt` is null.

My first guess is that your `FuzzyDateConverter` is not returning a null, or that `CompletedAt` is not a nullable.

Comment: I made the date nullable and set `CompletedAt = null` in my Model. It works, thanks...